# Retaining some starting elements of an array and set others to zero in R

Tags: arrays, r

Suppose in an array of order (`k*1*N`) where `k=a+b`, we want to retain first `a` elements of that array and replace remaining `b` elements equal to zero, thus forming another array of same order (`k*1*N`). How can we achieve this goal in R?

**Example**

```
set.seed(51214)
library(mvtnorm)
library(Matrix)
library(abind)
library(arrayhelpers)
library(reshape2)
##########################################################
N=1000
n=200
##########################################################
p1=2
p2=3
p=p1+p2
##########################################################
B1=c(1.5,2.5)
B2=rep(0,p2)
B=as.matrix(c(B1,B2),nrow=n)
##########################################################
avg=rep(0,p) 
sig=diag(p)
##########################################################
X=array(data=NA,dim=c(n,p,N))
BB=array(data=NA,dim=c(p,1,N))
XB=array(data=NA,dim=c(n,1,N))
Zi=array(data=NA,dim=c(n,1,N))
Yi=array(data=NA,dim=c(n,1,N))
Dat=array(data=NA,dim=c(n,p+1,N))
UE=array(data=NA,dim=c(p,1,N))
DD=array(data=NA,dim=c(p,1,N))
RE=array(data=NA,dim=c(p,1,N))
##########################################################
for(i in 1:N){
            X[,,i]=rmvnorm(n,mean=avg,sigma=sig)
            BB[,,i]=B
            XB[,,i]=X[,,i]%*%BB[,,i]
            Zi[,,i]=1/(1+exp(-XB[,,i]))
            Yi[,,i]=rbinom(n,1,Zi[,,i])
            Dat[,,i]=abind(Yi[,,i],X[,,i])
            df=melt(Dat[,,i])
            df1=subset(df,select=c(value))
            DT=as.data.frame(matrix(df1$value,ncol=p+1))
            colnames(DT)=c("y","x1","x2","x3","x4","x5")
            fit=glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+0,data=DT,family=binomial(link="logit"))
            UE[,,i]=as.matrix(fit$coefficients,ncol=5)
            RE[,,i]=
         }
```

Now we want a new array, say `RE` in such a way that starting (`p1*1*1000`) elements of `UE` are still there in `RE` but remaining (`p2*1*1000`) are zero.

Comment: `a1[4:5, , ] <- 0` ?

Comment: It worked perfectly well for the above example, but what if we are in loop `for i in 1:1000` then how we will implement this solution?

Comment: can you edit your question with the updated problem and an example? because as it is, I don't see where the problem is

Comment: @CathG, question is edited.

Comment: I still don't see the problem actually, you can still do `RE[(p1+1):(p1+p2), , ] <- 0` after the loop

Comment: or you can enter it in the `for loop` directly, like `RE[1:p1, ,i ] <- UE[1:p1, ,i] ; RE[(p1+1):(p1+p2), , i] <- 0`

Comment: Thanks @CathG. I m away at the moment. Apparently, its seems OK. I will inform when I get back to my lab. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CathG, your code worked well within the loop. Great.

Comment: @CathG, would you please create an answer for this question so that I may endorse as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill `RE` vector the way you want, you can do, inside the loop:

```
RE[1:p1, , i] <- UE[1:p1, , i] # fill the first p1 entries of first dimension with the same value as UE 
RE[(p1+1):(p1+p2), , i] <- 0 # fill the rest of the entries of first dimension with 0
```